# Pandas - Replace cell values using a conditional (normalising string input for gender)

Tags: python, pandas, string, conditional-statements

Example data

| id | Gender | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | F | 22 |
| 2 | Fem | 18 |
| 3 | male | 45 |
| 4 | She/Her | 30 |
| 5 | Male | 25 |
| 6 | Non-bianary | 26 |
| 7 | M | 18 |
| 8 | female | 20 |
| 9 | Male | 56 |

I want to be able to standardise this somewhat by replacing all cells with an 'F' in them with 'Female', and all cells with 'M' in them with 'Male'. I know the first step is to cast the whole column into capitals

```
df.Gender = df.Gender.str.capitalize()
```

and I know that I can do it value-by-value with

```
df['Gender'] = df['Gender'].replace(['F', 'Fem', 'Female'], 'Female')
```

but is there a way to do this somewhat programmatically?

such as

```
df.Gender = df.Gender.str.capitalise()

for i in df.Gender:
    if 'F' in str(i):
        #pd.replace call something like...
        df[df.Gender == i] = 'Female'
        #I know that line is very wrong
    elif 'M' in str(i)...
```

Comment: how about something like: `df['Gender'][df['Gender'].isin(['F', 'Fem', 'Female'])] = 'Female'`

Comment: Great. I can comment this as answer, and if it is preferred you can check it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using regex:

```py
import re

df["Gender"] = df["Gender"].str.replace(
    r"^F\S*$", "Female", flags=re.I, regex=True
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   id       Gender  Age
0   1       Female   22
1   2       Female   18
2   3         male   45
3   4      She/Her   30
4   5         Male   25
5   6  Non-bianary   26
6   7            M   18
7   8       Female   20
8   9         Male   56
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was hoping for but It does the job.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can loop through the df like that:

```
for indx, row in df.iterrows:
    if row["Gender"] == "F": #Or other conditions
        df.loc[index,"Gender"] = "Female"
    else:
        pass #or whatever condition u want to add
```

Is this what u asked for ?
Although its more efficient to do like that @Andrej Kesely Answered

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted. It might be less efficient in programming terms but it is more effecient for my needs and the capturing the correct info.

Answer (score 1):

```
df['Gender'][df['Gender'].isin(['F', 'Fem', 'Female'])] = 'Female'
```